# Constructor function style bank balance tool

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, constructor

I am trying to build a constructor function ... a simple bank balance overview.

This is my code:

```js
class BankAccount {
  constructor(amount = 0) {
    this.toal = amount;
  }
  balance(amount) {
    return this.amount
  }

  withdraw(amount) {
    this.amount - amount;
    return this.amount
  }

  deposit(amount) {
    this.amount + amount;
    return this.amount
  }
}
```

This is what I expect as example.

> // Example
>
> ```
> var account = new bankAccount(10)
> account.withdraw(2)
> account.withdraw(5)
> account.deposit(4)
> account.deposit(1)
> account.balance() // 8
> ```

It does not work. Where do I have the mistage?

Comment: `this.amount-amount;` etc... doesn't change the value of amount, you need to update it yourself by reassigning it (`this.amount = this.amount-amount;`)

Comment: also new BankAccount, not bankAccount as in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certain mistakes - 
In `var account = new bankAccount(10)`, the class name is `BankAccount`.

In the constructor you are assigning amount to `this.total` and later you are using `this.amount`, which is not a class member. Instead assign it to `this.amount`.

There is no need of parameter to balance method `balance(amount)` --> `balance()`.

In the `withdraw` method, you are deducting the parameter passed amount, however the final result should be stored in `this.amount`. `this.amount = this.amount - amount;`. Similar with the `deposit` method.

```js
class BankAccount {
  constructor(amount = 0) {
    this.amount = amount;
  }
  balance() {
    return this.amount
  }

  withdraw(amount) {
    this.amount = this.amount - amount;
    return this.amount
  }

  deposit(amount) {
    this.amount = this.amount + amount;
    return this.amount
  }
}

var account = new BankAccount(10)
account.withdraw(2)
account.withdraw(5)
account.deposit(4)
account.deposit(1)
console.log(account.balance()) // 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the `this.amount`. You should do it like this:

```
this.amount = this.amount-amount;
```

And

```
this.amount = this.amount+amount;
```

Otherwise the amount is always the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `amount` the return value of the expression, like below:

(Watch for a typo in `total` as well)

```js
class BankAccount {
    constructor (amount = 0) {
        this.total = amount;
    }
    balance(amount) {
        return this.amount
    }

    withdraw (amount) {
        this.amount = this.amount - amount;
        return this.amount
    }

    deposit(amount) {
        this.amount = this.amount + amount;
        return this.amount
    }
}
```